# Circumvent chrome data compression proxy in javascript

Tags: android, google-chrome, proxy

The mobile Chrome browser has a "chrome data compression proxy". Every request gets routed through that.

Which is quite annoying at times.
Is there a way to circumvent it, withouth the user having to disabling it inside the application?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, not easily.

Longer answer: Use https on your site and Chrome will not proxy the request.  For certain objects such as images you can also add the following header - "Cache-Control: no-transform" and the data compression proxy will not apply any transformations (such as compression).

Comment: What if the website is very simple and HTTPS is not available, and there is a simple captcha available which is stored in SESSION, and because of the proxy, the session is not applied on end-user. Is there a solution for this case?